# Regex to match specific-length string with white space in the middle (anywhere)

Tags: regex

I need a regex which will match a phrase (with specific length and structure) even if there is additional white space in the middle (anywhere).

Let's say we have some description:

```
Serial numbers: ABC1234567890 XYZ0987654321
```

Then we want to find all phrases matching to regex `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}`, but that description is malformed because of processing by external service. That service splits description to chunks, 12 digits each. So it will be:

```
Serial numbe
rs: ABC12345
67890 XYZ098
7654321
```

**Important**: "Serial numbers:" isn't fixed, it can be everything, so required phrases can be split anywhere (`ABC1 234567890`, `ABC1234567 890` etc.). New line and space have the same meaning from the phrase matching perspective, but in special cases there can be more white chars between parts of phrase (for example, space as last char of chunk + new line, multiple spaces in source description). It just simply should treat whole "white space" between two strings as 1 space (`ABC1 234567890` = `ABC1234     567890`, also with new line break). Those serials can be anywhere in malformed description (as I wrote: "Serial numbers:" part is optional, can be anything), also there can be more serial numbers within description. `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}` also is only an example, I want to know how to achieve matching with optional white space in the middle, but base regex can be different.

**EXPECTED RESULT**: collection of matched phrases (serial numbers from the example).

```
ABC1234567890
XYZ0987654321
```

**Info**: result can contain white chars within phrase (from above example it would be: `ABC12345 67890` and `XYZ098 7654321`). Most important thing is to match the base phrase (serial number).

Is it possible to make regex which will match it? I think it would be rather simple algorithm to match it without regex, but maybe it can be done with regular expression and make it "oneliner".

Comment: line break and space have different meanings which one?

Comment: @karakfa I have edited "Important" paragraph.

Comment: header still says ONE space! Can whitespace appear anywhere and any amount but only once? or multiple times as well such as `AB C   12 34    `

Comment: I've edited summary (title). I think one phrase can be split only once, so only one white space can occur in the middle, but can be more than one white char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will handle multiple spaces multiple times

```
(([A-Z]\s*){3}([0-9]\s*){10})
```

will match `AB C A A A A AD E12 34567890`
since `AD E12 34567890` fits the pattern

https://regex101.com/r/bK3sF8/1

Comment: Unfortunately it also matches things like `AB C A A A A AD E12 34567890`.. I've tried something similar, but `([A-Z\s]){3,}` matches whole capturing group multiple times rather than allowed chars inside a group.

Comment: After edit it seems like working really well! I'll make some more test later because my laptop is running out of battery.

Comment: I will do more tests when we'll be implementing this, our issue is still open, waiting for more important ones to be done. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

Just considering **one(you can adjust for multiples)** `\n` (break lines) in and outside the word here:`([\w\n?]*)`

You should try grouping the result

in this case:

> `/(([\w\n?]*)\s([\w\n?]*):\s([\w\n?]*)\n?\n?\s([\w\n]*))/ig`

you can get the serial number by groups $3 and $4

http://regexr.com/3d67n

Comment: As far as I understand your regex, it is fine-tailored for my example, but those serials can be anywhere (as I wrote: "Serial numbers:" part is optional, can be anything), also there can be more serial numbers within description. Also `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}` also is only example, I wanted to know how to achieve matching with optional white space in the middle, but base regex can be different.